# How i can call two actions one after the other in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a scenario where i call an index action which renders a tree structure,NOW i want that once that tree structure is made,i want to embeed another structure that i created from a js file within that structure,This js file is the response of another action in the same controller such as :-

```
    def index
     @pages.Page.all
    end

    def get_more_page
    @more_pages=Page.where(---some sql to fetch----)
     respond_to do |format|        
   format.js 
    end
   end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call to a function that calls both one after the other:

```
def call2func
    index
    get_more_page

end
```